# autocmd FileType vs ftplugin

Tags: vim, organization

What is the difference between placing:

```
autocmd FileType ruby setlocal ts=2
```

in my `~/.vimrc` and placing:

```
setlocal ts=2
```

in `~/.vim/ftplugin/ruby.vim`?

If there is no difference, where should I place commands that are specific to one filetype?

Comment: It is not a good example because `g:rubycomplete_buffer_loading` is a *global* variable that is to be put into vimrc without preceding `autocmd Filetype ruby`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't really a difference between the two.

I prefer to put commands like that in `ftplugin` and keep my main `.vimrc` language-agnostic… But there are no hard-and-fast rules. An advantage to keeping it in your `vimrc` would be that your vim settings would be easier to move around (ex, you could get all your vim settings on a new machine by simply copying your `.vimrc`, instead of `.vimrc` + `.vim`). Obviously putting them in your `.vimrc` will also have a minor performance penalty (ie, they will be loaded + executed for every file, not just ruby files)… But I wouldn't really worry about that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been placing code in `ftplugin` and i think I will continue to do so to keep my `.vimrc` simple.

Comment: How do you know there is a "performance penalty"? Could you explain how both approaches work (implementation details)?